# React – how to conditionally return one value (or a fallback)

Tags: reactjs

I have this code (edited for brevity):

```js
export default function Navigation({ page }) {
  return (
    <ul>
      {page.category.map((category) => (
        <>
          {(category.slug === exampleSlug)
            ? <li key={category._id}>{category.title}</li>
            : <li key={category._id}>All</li>
          }
        </>
      ))}
    </ul>
  )
}
```

It correctly returns either a category title or "All" for each category that a page has. Instead, I need it to return only one value (as opposed to one for each category). In plain text, if any one category slug matches the `exampleSlug`, display category title, otherwise display "All".

I've tried to solve it by using a `for` loop instead of a `map` method, such as if a condition is met return a value, otherwise fall back to another value, but it turns out that in this case I wouldn't be able to use `return`, only `Array.push` (please correct me if I'm wrong).

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only ever want to render exactly one `<li>`, either for the first category that matches or some fallback, then simply [look for a matching](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) category, and decide on whether one exists:

```
export default function Navigation({page}) {
  // find a matching category, it will be undefined if none exits
  const category = page.category.find(category => category.slug === exampleSlug);

  return (
    <ul>
        {/* render, based on whether a category was found */}
        <li>{undefined === category ? 'All' : category.title}</li>
    </ul>
  );
}
```

Comment: Yes maybe an additional state variable is too much but you don't consider the _id (that is unnecessary because the result is just one li =))

Comment: Yeah, it really depends on what @ytrewq actually wants. If the result should always be one element, no key is needed. ^^

Answer (score 0):

You could createa function `anyoneMatches` that takes `page.category, exampleSlug` and uses `find` to find the first categry that matches `exampleSlug`.

But you have a problem: in case matches, what `category.title` you want to show? The first that matches? If yes, you have to create a state variable called `category` and set it when you find the match. Something like:

```
const [category, setCategory] = useState({"_id": 0}); //<-- first match category

export default function Navigation({ page }) {
  return (
    <ul>
          {anyoneMatches(page.category, exampleSlug)
            ? <li key={category._id}>{category.title}</li>
            : <li key={category._id}>All</li>
          }
    </ul>
  )
}

const anyoneMatches = (categories, exampleSlug) => {
  let cat = categories.find(cat => cat.slug === exampleSlug); //<-- find first category that matches
  if (cat) setCategory(cat); //<-- if exists, call setCategory
  else setCategory({"_id": 0}); // else set category to default category (we need _id for li's key)
  return cat !== undefined; //<-- return a bool to condition html
}
```